# page view inside sliver to box adapter. flutter

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

i want a page view inside sliver to box adapter.

```
 SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child:  PageView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 260,
                          color: Colors.cyan,
                        ), 
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
         
            ),
```

All pages inside the page view must scroll without height according to widgets.
my error is,
Null check operator used on a null value.
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#2dd7a relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 0):

That just means, your `PageView` is unbound. Try this:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: SizedBox(
        height: 250,
        child: PageView.builder(...)
    ),
)
```

Comment: what if i want the pageview builder to expand all the available space ?